# amazon redshift disable full group by

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-redshift

Does Amazon Redshift have 'disable full group by' like MySQL, like the following query?

```
Disable full group by;
select 
a.prg_id
, a.uuid
, a.token_id
, a.itc
, sum(a.amount) 
, date_trunc(‘week’,a.date) as week

from abc 

group by 
a.prg_id
, a.uuid
, week
 ;
```

Comment: No.  That is brokenness that should be banished from MySQL.

Comment: Yes and no. Wouldn't it make aggregate functions complicated in a big giant query? @Go

Comment: What end-result do you want the query to achieve?

Comment: There is no benefit to write queries that way, even if it were possible on Redshift, just specify all the non-aggregate columns in the group by clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Redshift runs PostgreSQL, so if it exists on MySQL and not on PostgreSQL, it is unlikely to exist on Amazon Redshift.